# Has someone already used the XsdTypeImporterTask from XsdBuildTask.dll in MSBuild?

Tags: xsd, msbuild

I used to convert XSD files to CS files using the XSD.exe program.
I made a custom MSBuild Task to do that and it works quite well.

Now, I try to find an MSBuild Task to do it because I don't want to maintain my custom task anymore.

I found the XsdTypeImporterTask from the assembly XsdBuildTask.dll which seems to do that, according to the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.xsd.xsdtypeimportertask(v=vs.110).aspx).

However, that documentation is really poor and I didn't succeed to make it work, not even to import it in MSBuild :'(

I tried to Google and to StackOverflow this but didn't find anything about that.

Does someone on Earth use this Task?
Can someone help me using this Task?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after succeeding to use it, I can say that someone used it: me.

This [page](http://source.roslyn.io/#MSBuildFiles/C/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v4.0.30319/Microsoft.ServiceModel.targets) helped me understand how to use it.
It works very well!